# yii2 change other component assets

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

how can I change what library a widget should use ?

I changed the ones from the framework to use the min version lib

```
 'bundles' => [
                    'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                        'jsOptions' => ['position' => 1], //jQuery to be loaded before the body of the page
                        'js' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'jquery.min.js' : 'jquery.js'
                        ],
                    ],
                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                        'css' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'css/bootstrap.min.css' : 'css/bootstrap.css',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                        'js' => [
                            YII_ENV_DEV ? 'js/bootstrap.min.js' : 'js/bootstrap.js',
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
```

how can I set for other installed components the same thing ?
f.e kartik-v/yii2-widget-touchspin uses bootstrap-touchspin.css but I would like to set it to use the min version of the bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You may define **YII_ENV** as one of the following values:

**prod:** production environment. The constant YII_ENV_PROD will evaluate as true. This is the default value of YII_ENV if you do not define it.

**dev:** development environment. The constant YII_ENV_DEV will evaluate as true.

**test:** testing environment. The constant YII_ENV_TEST will evaluate as true.

```
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

add the code above in "/web/index.php" if does'nt work try

```
define('YII_ENV_DEV', true);
```

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-configurations#environment-constants